# Select only node with two times the same class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way to select an element with two times the same class on a webpage I don't own, so I have no ability to modify its markup.

I would expect that

`.abc.abc{background:blue}`

only impacts div with class `abc abc` but in fact is also impacts div with single `abc` class.

`div[class*=abc abc]{background:blue}` has the same issue.

```css
.abc{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  margin:5px;
}

.abc.abc{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='abc'></div>
<div class='abc'></div>
<div class='abc abc'></div>
```

Is there a selector so I can apply rule to div with class `abc abc` without affecting div with single class `abc` ?

Comment: did you try with quote `div[class*="abc abc"]`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif : That was my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a more specific target :)

```css
.abc{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}

div[class*="abc abc"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='abc'></div>
<div class='abc'></div>
<div class='abc abc'></div>
```

[View CodePen Solution](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/YMBPYz)